# Unity keeps on crashing suddenly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was using Unity version 2019.3.3f and it kept on crashing suddenly, both in play mode and editor mode,

I uninstalled both Unity and Unity Hub and removed all Unity files and caches, I then downloaded Unity version 2019.3.7f1 but the problem still occurs,

The following is the prompt I get from Unity when it crashes:
[Unity Crash Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzwyD.png)

When I check the logs in the following directory "C:\Users\ALIENWARE\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\upm.log", I get the following errors printed in the file:

> [2020-03-29T06:45:33.715Z][INFO] Starting Server
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:33.727Z][INFO] Server started on port [64005]
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:34.145Z][INFO] Health Request received
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.761Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.collab-proxy]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.762Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.ext.nunit]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.762Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.ide.rider]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.762Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.ide.vscode]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.762Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.render-pipelines.core]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.763Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.render-pipelines.universal]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.763Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.shadergraph]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.763Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.test-framework]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.763Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.763Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.timeline]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.763Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.xr.windowsmr.metro]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T06:45:39.763Z][WARN] Package folder
> [C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Project\Packages\com.unity.ugui]
> missing package manifest.
>
> [2020-03-29T07:27:29.946Z][ERROR] [Unity Package Manager (Upm)] Parent
> process [21428] was terminated

**NOTE:** when I tried to open the project on different machine, the project still crashes suddenly,

How should I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Do you have that file under that folder? CPP_Project/Packages/manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

This 3 things can help:

1. Log out from Unity Hub and restart it. After that unity should work.
2. Try to disable your firewall.
3. Try 1 after 2.

Comment: Still experiencing issues.. Tried everything from uninstalling / reinstalling / restarting my computer / restarting network adapters / turning firewall on and off. Nothing seems to work.